# How to mock DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, dbcontext

Here is the code I want to test

```cs
public DocumentDto SaveDocument(DocumentDto documentDto)
{
    Document document = null;
    using (_documentRepository.DbContext.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            if (documentDto.IsDirty)
            {
                if (documentDto.Id == 0)
                {
                    document = CreateNewDocument(documentDto);
                }
                else if (documentDto.Id > 0)
                {
                    document = ChangeExistingDocument(documentDto);
                }

                document = _documentRepository.SaveOrUpdate(document);
                _documentRepository.DbContext.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        _documentRepository.DbContext.RollbackTransaction();
        throw;
    }
}
return MapperFactory.GetDocumentDto(document);
```

}

And here is my test code

```cs
[Test]
public void SaveDocumentsWithNewDocumentWillReturnTheSame()
{
    //Arrange

    IDocumentService documentService = new DocumentService(_ducumentMockRepository,
            _identityOfSealMockRepository, _customsOfficeOfTransitMockRepository,
            _accountMockRepository, _documentGuaranteeMockRepository,
            _guaranteeMockRepository, _goodsPositionMockRepository);
    var documentDto = new NctsDepartureNoDto();


    //Act
    var retDocumentDto = documentService.SaveDocument(documentDto);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(documentDto, documentDto);
}
```

Once I run the test I get Null exception for the DbContext on the line

```
 using (_documentRepository.DbContext.BeginTransaction())
```

The problem I have is I don't have access to the DbContext. How would I go about solving it

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand you are injecting the repository through the constructor of Document Service as `ducumentMockRepository`.
So you can setup this mock with any expectations you want.

For your case you've to substitute DbContext by mock as well

```
// I hope you have an interface to abstract DbContext?
var dbContextMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDbContext>();

// setup expectations for DbContext mock
dbContextMock.Expect(...)

// bind mock of the DbContext to property of repository.DbContext
ducumentMockRepository.Expect(mock => mock.DbContext)
                      .Return(dbContextMock)
                      .Repeat()
                      .Any();
```