# How can I use DbContext in C# instead of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, dbcontext

I have some questions:

1. How can I use `DbContext` in C# instead of Entity Framework?
2. How can I mock `DbContext` in C#?

Please give me solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609430/how-to-mock-dbcontext?rq=1 you can see about second question

Answer (score -1):

[Testing with a mocking framework (EF6 onwards)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429)
[Testing with your own test doubles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314431)