# Unit test a method that sorts a collection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a method that sorts a collection based on a property like this:

```
public List<Student> GetAllStudents()
{
    return _studentCatalogContext.Student.Where(x => (x.Course != 2 && x.Course != 6))
                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.EnrollDateTime).ToList();
}
```

So the idea is to have, in this case, the most recently enrolled Student first.

Since the result of the method call will be a sorted list with the newest enrollment first I wrote a test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Calling_GetAllStudents_ReturnsSortedListOfStudents()
{
    var studentsList = new List<Student> {
    new Student {
                     Id = "123",
                     EnrollTime = "02/22/16 14:06:56 PM",
                     Course = 1
                 },
     new Student {
                     Id = "456",
                     EnrollTime = "03/30/16 12:50:38 PM",
                     Course = 3
                 }
                 };

    _studnentRepository.Setup(x=>x.GetAllStudents()).Returns(studentsList);

    Assert.AreEqual("02/22/16 14:06:56 PM", studentsList[0].EnrollTime);
}
```

It's been suggested that this test does is not valid in that it sets a value and then asserts on it.

How would I write a correct unit test in this case?

Comment: well in your case you would have to to *mock* the `_studentCatalogContext` which is most likely an `DbContext` right? It's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609430/how-to-mock-dbcontext

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Testing that a list is sorted correctly is largely irrelevant because it is an in-built framework method that (you would assume) has been tested and proven correct by the framework designers (Microsoft in this case).

A better test for this method would be to ensure that only students who are not in Course 2 or 6 are returned, since that is your custom logic inside the `Where` method.

So, your test could be something like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Calling_GetAllStudents_ReturnsSortedListOfStudents()
{
    var studentsList = new List<Student> {
    new Student {
                     Id = "123",
                     EnrollTime = "02/22/16 14:06:56 PM",
                     Course = 1
                 },
     new Student {
                     Id = "456",
                     EnrollTime = "03/30/16 12:50:38 PM",
                     Course = 2
                 }
                 };

    // mock out student repository to return list    

    var studentsList = _studentRepository.GetAllStudents();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, studentsList.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("123", studentsList[0].Id);
}
```

Comment: you would be surprised how many times I have seen errors in the LINQ-query - I would highly suggest testing those - in most BLOBAs those are the most complex code in the project!

Comment: @Carsten I'm advocating testing the logic part of the LINQ-query, which is the `Where` method. However, since the `OrderByDescending` contains no logic and is just a built-in method I don't see any value in testing it. In addition, you could argue that a Order By statement is for UI only and could be covered in UI testing rather than unit testing.

Comment: and if OP forgets it or someone accidently refactored it out, ... - it's one part of the things you should test if it's important

Comment: as your proposed solution is now you are doing exactly nothing ... (you test the list you setup yourself - there isn't even a `Where`) - also the test seems to be failing ... I would reject this on a code-review

Comment: you both know that you *mock away* the very method you are supposed to be testing?

Comment: @Carsten you're correct there, I've updated the answer to not return the mocked list. Presumably the OP would be mocking the data context to return the correct data set.

Comment: which is my initial comment ... but the test is still dead wrong (even if OP magically replaces the comment which was the question after all) - OP is sorting descending and so `123` would not be on the first `Id` - I know this is the C# tag where you have to shoot fast - but it should be somewhat helpful and correct don't you think?

Comment: also not that you **don't** actually target the `Where` part at all - as you did not include any filtered-out `Course`s - see testing simple queries can be hard ...

Comment: @Carsten my point was that while testing the order clause is unnecessary (and I still maintain that) there is benefit to testing the where and my example (simple and perhaps incomplete it may be) was to demonstrate that.

Comment: Testing the sort is called correctly is  highly relevant to the code under test.  In it's current form, the OP appears to be expecting the wrong record to be returned (the test expects ascending order whilst the code implements descending order).

Answer (score 2):

You test as it stands is a null test (it tests that the list you constructed has the first element that you just put there).

In it's current form, your [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36855175/592182) has the same problem.  It sets up a mock of your repository and then validates that the mock returns the information that you've told the mock to.

To test the repositories logic effectively, you need to mock its dependencies, which in this case is the `_studentCatalogContext`.  Since you haven't provided this in your question, I'm going to assume the following classes:

```
public class Student {
    public string Id {get;set;}           // Weird this is a string not int
    public string  EnrollTime {get;set;}  // Weird this is a string not date
    public int Course  {get;set;}
}

public class StudentCatalogContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual IDbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }
}

public class StudentRepository
{
    private StudentCatalogContext _studentCatalogContext;
    public StudentRepository(StudentCatalogContext context)
    {
        _studentCatalogContext = context;
    }
    public List<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        return _studentCatalogContext.Student.Where(x => (x.Course != 2 && x.Course != 6))
                                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.EnrollTime).ToList();
    }
}
```

Notice, I am injecting the catalog context into the repository.  This is required, so that it can be mocked.  Also, notice that I've renamed `EnrolledDateTime` in your LINQ query to `EnrollTime` so that it matches the rest of your code sample.

This code can then be tested as follows:

```
// Construct the data to be returned by the student set mock.
// Note, you don't want this to be in the order that you're expecting
// otherwise, how do you know if it's been sorted...
var studentData = new List<Student> {
    new Student {
                     Id = "123",
                     EnrollTime = "02/22/16 14:06:56 PM",
                     Course = 1
                 },
     new Student {
                     Id = "456",
                     EnrollTime = "03/30/16 12:50:38 PM",
                     Course = 3
                 }
}.AsQueryable();

// Setup a mock of the student set, which returns the canned data
// prepared above
var dbSetMock = new Mock<IDbSet<Student>>();
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(studentData.Provider);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(studentData.Expression);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(studentData.ElementType);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(studentData.GetEnumerator());

// Create a mock of the catalog context that returns
// the mocked set prepared above
var contextMock = new Mock<StudentCatalogContext>();
contextMock.Setup(x=>x.Student).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);

// Create the system under test, injecting the mock context
var repo = new StudentRepository(contextMock.Object);

// Call the method that we're actually testing
var fetchedData = repo.GetAllStudents();

// Validate that the information returned is what we're expecting
Assert.AreEqual("02/22/16 14:06:56 PM", fetchedData[0].EnrollTime);
```

It's worth pointing out that the above test fails.  This is because the code under test sorts EnrollTime descending, so the first item in the list is the one with the EnrollTime of "03/30/16 12:50:38 PM"