# Unit testing first, Database Count using LINQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

Since I'm now practicing a unit test first development process I had this question while doing the unit test.

I have to create a test that'll verify or assert the items that it will count in a specific table in the database. Also, it has parameters.

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void verify_items_count()
  {
      //Arrange
      Mock<IRepository> Repo = new Mock<IRepository>();
      Repo.Setup(t => t.Query().Count(r => r.Id == "**WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE IF THIS IS ONLY A MOCK**")).Returns(12);

      //Act
      //Assert
  }
```

Seems like it'll be none sense if I assert it checking if it returns 12 having also its parameters since we all know that it doesn't call in the DB. I've set it to 12, though.

***Please help me how to write a unit test first.***
I was thinking if it is supposed to be in an integration testing.
But I've read that everything should start in unit testing. So I believe there is a way.

Comment: What class are you actually testing with this? Looks like you are tesing the Mock..

Comment: I don't actually get it. I have to count items in the database. But since I don't have to connect with the DB. I have to mock it. In the actual code I'll probably use that kind of LINQ query that is why I'm setting it up.

Comment: So the counting code is something you write yourself? You shall only test your own code..

Comment: You *probably* want to mock the database context used by your repository.  Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36862759/592182

Answer (score 0):

Do no mock your repository. Instead create a `DummyRepository` which implements your `IRepository` for e.g. If you have `IRepository` strucuture like this

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Add<T>( T entity ) where T : class;
    T Get<T>( int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes ) where T : BaseEntity;
    IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>( params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes ) where T : class;
    void Remove<T>( T entity ) where T : class;
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

then your DummyRepository should do this

```
public class DummyRepository : IRepository
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Object> _database;

    public DummyRepository()
    {
        _database = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public void Add<T>( T entity ) where T : class
    {
        var table = GetEntityTable<T>();

        var entityBase = entity as BaseEntity;
        if ( entityBase == null )
            throw new NotImplementedException( "You must inherit from entity base" );

        if ( entityBase.Id == 0 )
        {
            var idToUse = table.Any() ? table.Max( x => ( x as BaseEntity ).Id ) + 1 : 1;
            typeof( BaseEntity ).GetProperty( "Id" ).SetValue( entityBase, idToUse );
            table.Add( entity );
        }
        else
        {
            var itemInList = table.FirstOrDefault( x => ( x as BaseEntity ).Id == entityBase.Id );
            if ( itemInList == null )
                table.Add( entity );
            else
            {
                var itemIndex = table.IndexOf( itemInList );
                table[ itemIndex ] = entity;
            }
        }
    }


    private List<T> GetEntityTable<T>() where T : class
    {
        List<T> table;
        if ( _database.ContainsKey( typeof( T ) ) )
            table = (List<T>)_database[ typeof( T ) ];
        else
        {
            table = new List<T>();
            _database.Add( typeof( T ), table );
        }
        return table;
    }

    public T Get<T>( int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes ) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        if ( !_database.ContainsKey( typeof( T ) ) )
            return null;
        return ( (List<T>)_database[ typeof( T ) ] ).FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id == id );
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>( params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes ) where T : class
    {
        if ( _database.ContainsKey( typeof( T ) ) )
            return ( (List<T>)_database[ typeof( T ) ] ).AsQueryable();
        return new List<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public void Remove<T>( T entity ) where T : class
    {
        if ( _database.ContainsKey( entity.GetType() ) )
            ( (IList)_database[ entity.GetType() ] ).Remove( entity );
    }

    public void SaveChanges() { }
}
```

by the way you would need a BaseEntity for this example to work which is like this

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So in your test start, you need to `Add` data and hopefully you would be able to write your tests which can check your queries.

The code below won't comile because you don't have Service class but I'm jusy giving you an example here on how to use it.

```
IRepository repository = new DummyRepository();
repository.Add(new BaseEntity { Id = 1 } );
var service = new Service(repository);
```

Answer (score 0):

A naïve first test would probably be

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void verify_items_count()
  {
      //Arrange
      var expectedCount = 3;
      var repository = MakeRepositoryWithElements(expectedCount);

      //Act
      var actualCount = repository.Count();

      //Assert
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);
  }
```

Under the covers, `MakeRepositoryWithElements(n)` must manage to

- Instantiate a *real* Repository. Not a mock or a stub, because you want to test the real implementation of Count(). That's what the test is all about.
- Put n elements in the repository.

The textbook, long-winded way of doing this would probably be :

1. Implement `MakeRepositoryWithElements()` and `Count()` directly as SQL queries against a real database.
2. The test passes
3. In the Refactor step of your TDD cycle, realize that :

   - Testing against the real DB is slow and requires a lot of data cleanup if you want to reuse the same database as the data source of consecutive tests.
   - Your platform already provides an abstraction on top of SQL that does the query heavy lifting for you and exposes collections of objects instead of database tables. I.e. some kind of `DatabaseContext`. Conveniently enough, the database context has an interface (or you create one around it) that you can implement to make your own fast, in-memory version. In tests, you connect your repository to that version instead of the full fledged `DatabaseContext`.

So you would refactor until each object strictly adheres to the Single Reponsibility Principle - the Repository only reasons about collections of objects while the DatabaseContext is about the underlying persistence technology - and the test runs fast and in memory. Something along these lines

```
public class WhateverRepository
{
  private IDatabaseContext _dbContext;

  public WhateverRepository(IDatabaseContext databaseContext) 
  {  
    _dbContext = databaseContext;
  }

  public int Count()
  {
    // This is possible because the context exposes collections of objects to us
    return _dbContext.Whatevers.Count(); 
  }
}

public WhateverRepository MakeRepositoryWithElements(int elementCount)
{
  var context = new InMemoryDatabaseContext();
  for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
  {
    context.Whatevers.Add(new Whatever());
  }
  return new WhateverRepository(context);
}
```

If you're an experienced developer or have already implemented such a repository in your system, you will probably directly jump to the refined solution.

In the end, note that **`Count()` is a trivial one-liner** that doesn't involve any logic if the data is already exposed to you in the form of object collections, because the platform gives you Count() for free. Therefore, **you might want to skip this test altogether**, unless you still want to go through the motions of it to practice some TDD, or you want to use the test as a "starter" that will get you a first decoupled implementation of the Repository and a few test helper methods.