# Mocking DbContext Entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing

I am testing a function that contains this code:

```
void FunctionToTest() {
  if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            // [...]
        }

  // [...]
}
```

For this reason I created my own test context that works well but I am not able to mock `DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity)` as the `DbEntityEntry` class has a constructor that requires an internal class.

Any solution for this?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  If your using EF Core, you can use the InMemoryDatabaseProvider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609430/how-to-mock-dbcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Effort](https://effort.codeplex.com/). Download it via NuGet, add this code to your app.config

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="Effort.Provider" invariant="Effort.Provider" description="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderFactory,Effort" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data><entityFramework>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Effort.Provider" type="Effort.Provider.EffortProviderServices, Effort" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Now in your test you can simply add

```
EffortProviderConfiguration.RegisterProvider();
var connection = DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
var model = new ApplicationDbContext(connection);
model.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

And voila you have a fake database for testing purposes

Comment: Is there another solution without installing another package?